# Mysterious junction box in bathroom

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, safety, junction-box

In my house there is a junction box near the floor in the bathroom. It was presumably installed by or on behalf of a prior owner who did some renovations on the lower floor.

Here it is in all its circular glory:

[image: mystery box]

Though it is not shown in the photo, the shower is off to the left, only about 1 meter from the box. I am concerned about the safety of this arrangement should water come out of the shower, the floor be wet, etc.

There is only a single wire going from the wall into the junction box, like the white wire in this cable:

[image: several household 3-core wires]

This seems to indicate to me that this was some dead-end wire left after renovations. I tested it with an non-contact voltage tester and it did not trigger (i.e., the NCV showed no voltage present, but I don't know how reliable these are).

Should I be worried and what I can do to make this safer?

Comment: It looks like a weather/water tight box, instead of a normal box used in houses.  If it is for a dead cable then it should be safe, but your toe will think differently.

Comment: Have you opened the access panel to see if the electrical cable is visible from inside?

Comment: @Mark - I haven't. You mean the one near the floor to the right of the box? If I open it, what should I look for?

Comment: @crip659 - heh, it's harder to stub your toe on this one than it might look because the toilet sort of overhangs it and blocks out most of that space.

Comment: The big round one with the two screws.  Looks like a black rubber gasket on it to seal.  Your toe thanks you/them for the placement.

Answer (score 5):

If I were you, I'd investigate a little further. Get a real volt meter and do a voltage check. Also, check in your main panel to see if there's a breaker that controls this cable.The cable might have been pulled into the main panel but not connected to anything. It could have been installed for a future Point of service water heater or maybe a heated bidet. Those access panels might provide a clue too, access to plumbing fixtures.